# having close button stick to upper right of video

Tags: html, css

I have a video playing full screen when you first go to my page. I want to have a close button on the upper right corner but I can only keep it on the upper right of the window not the actual video

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atSBc/6/)

```
  <div id="vid">
   <a href="#" class="close_vid"/></a>
   <video  width="100%" height="100%" autoplay>
   <source src="aa.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   <source src="aa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="aa.webm" type="video/webm">
   <object data="aa.mp4"  width="100%" height="100%">
   <embed  width="100%" height="100%" src="movie.swf">
  </object>
 </video>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#vid {
 background-color: black;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 list-style: none outside none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 900;
}

#vid .close_vid {
 background: url(icons/zoom-on.png) no-repeat;
 top: 6px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 290px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 width: 29px;
 z-index: 999;
 right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111175/placing-a-div-in-front-of-a-flash-embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#vid .close_vid {
    position: relative;
}
```